# Cómo se pasan las series de dataframes a arrays en python

Tags: python, array, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Tras agrupar datos de un dataframe por días y obteniendo el percentil 10,25,75 y 90 para cada uno de ellos obtengo los datos en un dataframe llamado `selectedDataPercentile` con la siguiente estructura como resultado:

```
              Date         Level
0 0.10  2019-03-07        102.20
  0.25  2019-03-07        121.75
  0.75  2019-03-07        188.75
  0.90  2019-03-07        207.90
1 0.10  2019-04-07        133.50
  0.25  2019-04-07        143.00
  0.75  2019-04-07        173.75
  0.90  2019-04-07        185.50
```

Si uso el comando `values` de Pandas de la siguiente manera `selectedDataPercentile.values` obtengo lo siguiente:

```
array([[datetime.date(2019, 3, 7), 102.2],
       [datetime.date(2019, 3, 7), 121.75],
       [datetime.date(2019, 3, 7), 188.75],
       [datetime.date(2019, 3, 7), 207.9],
       [datetime.date(2019, 4, 7), 133.5],
       [datetime.date(2019, 4, 7), 143.0],
       [datetime.date(2019, 4, 7), 173.75],
       [datetime.date(2019, 4, 7), 185.5]], dtype=object)
```

También he probado a usar el comando`to_numpy`, pero sin éxito.

**Lo que a mi me gustaría sería pasar las series y tuplas a un array de manera que no quede cada percentil en un array diferente, si no que me queden los percentiles 10,25,75 y 90 de la misma fecha en un array. ¿Ideas? El resultado ideal sería de la siguiente forma:**

```
array([[datetime.date(2019, 3, 7), 102.2, 121.75, 188.75, 207.9],
       [datetime.date(2019, 4, 7), 133.5, 143.0, 173.75, 185.5]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que como consecuencia del agrupamiento, tienes un índice jerárquico (multiindex).

Para poder reproducir exactamente tu ejemplo necesitaría saber cómo has llegado al dataframe que muestras al principio. De momento lo hago con un datframe como el siguiente (que creo que es igual al tuyo, pero no estoy seguro). Este dataframe tiene un índice de dos niveles y he puesto nombres a estos niveles: el primero lo llamé "i" y el segundo "perc". En tu caso no tienen nombres, pero creo que esto no afecta al procedimiento. Este es mi dataframe de partida, `df`:

```
              Date   Level
i perc                    
0 0.10  2019-03-07  102.20
  0.25  2019-03-07  121.75
  0.75  2019-03-07  188.75
  0.90  2019-03-07  207.90
1 0.10  2019-04-07  133.50
  0.25  2019-04-07  143.00
  0.75  2019-04-07  173.75
  0.90  2019-04-07  185.50
```

Ahora hay que añadir la columna "Date" al índice jerárquico:

```
df = df.set_index("Date", append=True)
```

El resultado es casi idéntico al de partida, solo que ahora "Date" en vez de ser una columna es parte del índice:

```
                    Level
i perc Date              
0 0.10 2019-03-07  102.20
  0.25 2019-03-07  121.75
  0.75 2019-03-07  188.75
  0.90 2019-03-07  207.90
1 0.10 2019-04-07  133.50
  0.25 2019-04-07  143.00
  0.75 2019-04-07  173.75
  0.90 2019-04-07  185.50
```

Lo siguiente es "desapilar" el nivel "perc". Es difícil explicar qué hace esto, pero es fácil de comprender si lo ves en acción:

```
df = df.unstack(level=1)
```

El resultado es:

```
              Level                       
perc           0.10    0.25    0.75   0.90
i Date                                    
0 2019-03-07  102.2  121.75  188.75  207.9
1 2019-04-07  133.5  143.00  173.75  185.5
```

Ahora ya tienes los datos como los quieres, para extraerlos en forma de array. Un `df.values` te dará los números:

```
[[102.2  121.75 188.75 207.9 ]
 [133.5  143.   173.75 185.5 ]]
```

Aunque esto no nos da las fechas (porque están en el índice, y no en los valores). Si quieres también las fechas, quitémoslas del índice:

```
df = df.reset_index(level=1)
```

Ahora el dataframe está así:

```
            Date  Level                       
perc                0.1    0.25    0.75    0.9
i                                             
0     2019-03-07  102.2  121.75  188.75  207.9
1     2019-04-07  133.5  143.00  173.75  185.5
```

Y ahora sí, `df.values` te da:

```
[['2019-03-07' 102.2 121.75 188.75 207.9]
 ['2019-04-07' 133.5 143.0 173.75 185.5]]
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! No conocía el concepto de "unstack" en los dataframes. Es muy útil para cuando obtienes multiindex.